# onchange event on a textbox when i type a number or string

Tags: html, textbox, onchange, sos

So i got this exercise at my school and i cant for the life of me find the answer here is : Take advantage of the onchange event to make a page with a text box where if the user types a number, it will turn yellow if you type a String then turn green and leave it blank to make it red.
please help

Comment: Show an attempt...

Comment: i dont know where to use the onchange event

Comment: Since you are in a class which covers HTML and JavaScript you should be able to show us a text box at minimum. If you can't do that, google should provide dozens if not hundreds of examples. https://www.google.com/search?q=html+textbox+onchange

Answer (score 0):

Ok, First, You need to do something, show some code or anything else, otherwise, nobody could help you because is your homework and that's not correct.

Second, take a look on this:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

That's an example how to use Onchange event in a HTML tag. You also need to take a look on how to add classes or style to a HTML tag using Javascript.

Nothing else I can tell you without doing your work.

Good luck. If you have any doubt, after do something, let me know.